# How to create a recovery partition in memory

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery

How can I create a recovery partition in memory as an option when booting the PC so that I can check all partitions including the system one that typically loads Ubuntu. This way I can fsck for example the partition that is normally running Ubuntu but without having it running it at that moment.

The recovery partition would have access to some tools to check the disck, memory, etc.

Is this doable?

Just to clarify with the whole recovery partition, I would boot the PC and load the normal GRUB menu but it would have an additional option to load some kind of image that would load into memory and from there it would start the system (Everything running from memory). So I could for example, do a fsck on all hard drives and do other checking while taking the advantage of the increased speed of using the memory to host the recovery system (Without using the hard drives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you would actually have to access the memory and partition it at the BIOS level. Instruct the BIOS to, or not to, parse the the allocated memory blocks when booting.

It would add another level of security also. Recovery accessed by using a administrative password.

In theory this would be as a SSD only living on the RAM. If this were to work there would be no need for a grub loader as all the hard instruction would load when you pressed the power button. Sweet!!! instant on.

I don't know of any way to flash the memory with that kind of detailed instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could create an additional partition on your hard drive for recovery purposes. Another option would be to image the disk you'd like to protect. Remember, though, that if your bootloader program (such as GRUB) fails then you will need another strategy. I have successfully restored systems with damaged bootloaders by using a live cd, and you will definitely want to have a live cd with the latest Ubuntu distro just in case.

You might want to see the documentation for Ubuntu file recovery, as well:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Make sure the hard drive partition containing Ubuntu is "unmounted" before creating a new partition. First, make a live cd and then use it to open a partition manager:

1. Follow the instructions to create a live cd or usb if you don't already have one:

   http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download
2. Boot from your live cd, just like you probably did when you installed Ubuntu for the first time.
3. Open a partition manager such as "GParted". Follow the on-screen instructions carefully to create a new partition while minimizing changes to existing partitions (When you choose a file system for the new partition, keep in mind that some file system types aren't recognized by Windows). Be careful--it's very easy to make a mistake here.
4. You will probably want to make this new partition bootable. The partition manager should allow you to flag it as "bootable", but make sure to install some sort of operating system to it if you intend to boot from it. Make sure your bootloader recognizes the new partition upon boot. If you are using GRUB, you may be able to edit the operating system menu directly by changing an entry in the "grub" file:

   http://www.hackourlife.com/change-default-boot-order-for-grub-2-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

Information on creating a recovery disk image is posted here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Extract_filesystem_from_recovered_image

Comment: Am asking for a partition that loads in memory. Without using any hard drive. For example an image that grub loads in memory that includes everything needing to work.